# How to convert 7sec Video to Gif Android

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg

Am making an app that convert shot video clips to Gif. i was wondering if there was a libary that directly converts videos to gifs on the Fly on Android.

I've tried to extract all the frames of the video and encode them into a gif but am only getting the the first frame of the video. my code is below:

```
         public static final int GIF_DELAY_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 100;  
         public static final float SPEED_RATIO = 1.1f; 

         Uri videoFileUri=Uri.parse(mOutputFile.toString());
        FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(mOutputFile.getAbsolutePath());
         rev = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(RecorderActivity.this, videoFileUri);
         int millis = mp.getDuration();
         for(int i=1000000;i<millis*1000;i+=1000000){
            Bitmap bitmap =           retriever.getFrameAtTime(i,FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
        rev.add(bitmap);

        }   

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try{
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/test.gif");
            outStream.write(generateGIF());
            outStream.close();
         }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }


        public byte[] generateGIF() {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
        encoder.setDelay((int)(GIF_DELAY_BETWEEN_FRAMES * (1 / SPEED_RATIO)));
        encoder.start(bos);
        for (Bitmap bitmap : rev) {
            encoder.addFrame(bitmap);
        }
        encoder.finish();
        return bos.toByteArray();
     }
```

Please help me guys...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Take look on JMF (Java Media Framework). It will take you some time to
>   learn basics. Then you will able to do this. I do not have a code
>   sample with me now but as far as I remember you have to create player,
>   then retrieve from it appropriate "control" that provides you access
>   to frames.
>
> Here is an example for start:
>   http://khemsoi.blogspot.com/2006/03/jmf-frame-grabber.html

FROM [Lib/API for create small gif from video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580056/lib-api-for-create-small-gif-from-video)

Comment: Thanks.. i'll work on learning it. but in the meantime do you have any other more straight forward approaches?.thanks

Comment: That gives it in only a short 'snippet' of code does it not?

Comment: But unfortunately java.awt.Image is not supported in android.